# SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out when in Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, jar, collabnet

I'm trying to upload a file to Sourceforge and create a file release for it using the Collabnet API and SOAP in Java, in Eclipse, This works fine until I pack the class into a jar, add it to the build path, and try to execute it via an Ant Java task. Then I get the fault given below fi_sfSoap.upLoadFile hangs and then times out. It's not the size of the file and at first I thought it was the file paths but the file can be read by a file reader from inside the jar. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
File latest_release = new File(file_path);
    if(!latest_release.canRead()){
        System.out.println("File does not Exist");
}else{
        DataSource ds = new FileDataSource(latest_release);
        DataHandler dh = new DataHandler(ds);
    try{
            String file_id = fi_sfSoap.uploadFile(sessionId, dh);
            f_sfSoap.createFrsFile(sessionId, release_id, fileName, "application/zip", file_id);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Error message

```
    [java] AxisFault
    [java]  faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
    [java]  faultSubcode: 
    [java]  faultString: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    [java]  faultActor: 
    [java]  faultNode: 
    [java]  faultDetail: 
    [java]  {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    [java]  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    [java]  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess your file is too large to upload.

BTW `!latest_release.canRead()` does not unambiguously mean that the file doesn't exist. It could exist but be inaccessible due to access control.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try looking at the access control. The problem persists with a simple text file though and the real problem is the fact that it can upload the same file, just when it's not packed into a jar.